# escape html twice in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, attributes, escaping, tooltip

I am using Bootstrap tooltips for displaying user generated content. But i also use the option `html: true` because I want to enable html in the tooltip to be able to use some formatting.

Let's say i have a user content as follows:

```
<script>alert('e')</script>
```

It is escaped server side, put into the title attribute of some div, and sent to the browser like this:

```
<div title="&lt;script&gt;alert('e')&lt;/script&gt;">Bla</div>
```

But the browser will unescape the html entities, and when i call the tooltip function on the div, it will have the following title attribute value:

```
<div title="<script>alert('e')</script>">Bla</div>
```

Which will cause the alert to be fired. So what I would need is to escape the content of the title attribute twice, so that it's sent like this:

```
<div title="&amp;lt;script&amp;gt;alert('e')&amp;lt;/script&amp;gt;">Bla</div>
```

And when tooltip is called, it would still look like this:

```
<div title="&lt;script&gt;alert('e')&lt;/script&gt;">Bla</div>
```

So the alert would not be executed.

What is the proper way to do this in Rails? Is there something I am missing here? Please don't tell me to use the option `html: false` of the tooltip module as I need html formatting.

Answer (score 0):

I would try for HTML:

```
<div title="<%= escape_javascript("<script>alert(\"e\");</script>") %>">Bla</div>
```

However I wonder why you want to allow users to inject script tags into the tooltips?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Sadly it doesn't work, as the code above produces:
`<script>alert(\'e\')<\/script>` which results in the script tag still being executed (but with invalid javascript inside)